# Video streaming using gstreamer, lower network usage to 200kbs or under

Tags: bash, video-streaming, gstreamer, mp4, rtp

Not very familiar with Gstreamer, currently editing a bash script to configure camera video for an RTP MP4 network stream.

The intent was to get the best possible compression as I don't have a lot of bandwidth on the network side, best case would be under 200kbs

By default I believe x264enc is using 2048kbs and would like to change this.

Image quality, framerate and resolution are secondary to limiting bandwidth.

I'm very new to being an active participant on stackoverflow and will continue to look at the resources provided but any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Current Bash Script

````
#!/bin/bash

REMOTE_IP=192.168.0.10
REMOTE_PORT=7000
WIDTH=640
HEIGHT=420
FRAMERATE=30

gst-launch-1.0 -vv -e v412src device=/dev/video0 !"video/x-raw, width=$WIDTH,height=$HEIGHT,framerate=$FRAMERATE/1" ! queue ! x264enc speed-preset=1 ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=$REMOTE_IP port=$REMOTE_PORT```
````

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `gst-launch-1.0`? (Is there any, or is it combined with `gstreamer`?). Sometime common options to a app system have a separate man page. Look at the bottom of man pages for the `see also` section. ....

Comment: AND  ... Sorry, but Stackoverflow is dedicated to helping solve `if/then/else` programming code (and tools) problems. Your question seems to be about using and configuring *nix tools. Best to delete here and repost to  [unix.se] . 
Good luck.